# Problems with the number $0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Here is the original formula:
$$\frac{256}{2^x}=y$$
In order to solve for $x$, I've done this:
$$\log_{2}\left(\frac{256}{y}\right)=x$$
The problem is that $y$ can be zero. What should I do to solve for $x$?

Comment: So $i$ is just a variable, and not the usual imaginary unit?

Comment: Correct, $s$ is also normal. (I probably should change them)

Comment: So $s$ has become $x$, and $i$ has become $y$

Comment: If you are going to change the variables in the equations, you should change them in the text as well.  It would make it easier to understand.

Comment: $y$ cannot equal zero, because $\frac{256}{2^x}$ can never be equal to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rewrite $\dfrac{256}{2^x} = y$ as $256 = y \times 2^x$, then it is clearly impossible to have $y=0$ while remaining within the real numbers, as 256 is not a multiple of 0.  Since $2^x$ is positive for all real $x$, you must have $y>0$.

So $x = \log_2 \left( \dfrac{256}{y} \right) = 8 - \log_2 \left( y \right)$ is fine.

On the other hand, it *is* possible to have $x=0$, in which case $2^x = 1$ and so $y = 256$ and $\log_2 \left( y \right) = 8$.

Comment: Here let me change the equation to $\frac{256}{2^{((n+s) \mod 8)}}=256-m$ this proably makes more sense now.

Comment: I think that is a different question

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $\ $ Rewrite it as $\rm\ Y = 2^{\:8 - X}$